# PHP jQuery Ajax Call Only Works in Chrome, not in other Browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to execute a MySQL update based on a list of inactive users.  I simply want to update the database field with a number 1.  I was able to get this working flawlessly in Chrome but have been unsuccessful in Firefox.  Ive looked at tons of other similar issues here in StackOverflow but cant find a solution.  Since this is working in Chrome, I figure the issue is with my jQuery AJAX call:

```
<script src="../bin/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function reactivateThisUser(id)
        {
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reactivate-user.php",
        data: 'id='+id,
        cache: false,
        });
    }
</script>
```

And later in the HTML body im using the following code, which is executing the jQuery function:

```
echo "<button type='submit' onclick='reactivateThisUser(".$row["id"].");' id='reactivateButton".$row["id"]."'>Reactivate User</button>";
```

Im not sure what im missing here but ive beaten my head in on this one.  Im sure its something really simple missing.

Just in case, here is my php code from reactivate-user.php:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$reactivateThisUser = @$_POST['id'];

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); }

$sql = "UPDATE table SET is_active='1' WHERE id='$reactivateThisUser'";

if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("location: ../view-all-users");
        exit;
        $link->close();
        } else {
        header("location: ../error/3");
        exit;
        $link->close();
        }

?>
```

Comment: Don't use the @ operator to hide error messages: you won't know what's going on. DO use prepared queries to guard against SQL Injection attacks. There's no point in putting code after an `exit` statement - your program will exit before it's executed (your database connections are close automatically anyway)

Comment: Why are you using "@" in front of the `$_POST['id'];` statement. The @ suppresses any warnings, and will make debugging harder if something goes wrong.

Comment: Aside the previous comments about PHP... I see no reason why the jQuery ajax would behave differently from Chrome to FireFox.

Comment: I went ahead and cleaned up the PHP a bit, I removed the @ before the POST variable and moved exit to after the closing of the DB connection.  Thanks for the pointers everyone, however FireFox is still not performing the AJAX call for some odd reason...

Comment: Testing methodology: Did you reset the database `is_active` to `0` for the targetted `id` before each tests? -- Issues often are dumb like this. ;)

Comment: Hey Louys, no I didnt.  I have a similar page w/script that is deactivating the user account (from a value of 1 to a 2).  Im able to perform the enable/disable just fine in Chrome and am able to watch the SQL table update in realtime.  The issue here is really just with FireFox not executing the AJAX call, which for some reason Chrome is able to perform without any issues or hiccups.  Also no errors are being thrown in Firefox.

Comment: The FF and Chrome inspectors are quite similar on this. After a `button` click, check the network tab... Click the `reactivate-user.php` item and look at the request header.

Comment: I set this up and ran it in Firefox. The AJAX request is sent, exactly as it should be. Have you disabled JavaScript in your Firefox?

Comment: lolll @TangentiallyPerpendicular: NICE catch is that is the issue! I would never have think about that.

Comment: Javascript is not disabled in FireFox.

Comment: Need also to review entire `js` and `html` format since if any errors there ajax will not be call (maybe chorome could force something ...)

Comment: Regarding checking the network tab, I am seeing an error on the POST being performed to the reactivate-user.php file.  Under the transferred column, the error states NS_BINDING_ABORTED.  Unfortunately there are no other details.  I just tried removing the cache: false, from the javascript code but the same issue persists.

Comment: Try to add a `.fail()` handler to the ajax...  `jQuery.ajax({...}).fail(function(req,status,message){console.log(req,status,message);})`

Comment: I added your code at the end of my function and im now seeing the following two errors in my console.  The first error appears before running the functioning (just loading the page) and the other appears after trying to run the function:

Error #1:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Error #2:
Uncaught ReferenceError: reactivateThisUser is not defined
    onclick reactivate-user/?:1

Comment: DANM! I think I found it. DO YOU preventDefault() on your submit button? Here is the google search [result](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-analytics-questions/ns-binding-aborted-error-in-httfox/qaq-p/209435) I got searching on `NS_BINDING_ABORTED`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I was testing that idea as you posted your comment. See my answer below

Comment: Oh wow, so they are saying there needs to be a delay set once the submit button is clicked.  No I do not have a preventDefault() function set anywhere.  How and where should that go?  Currently my submit buttons are generated from a WHILE script outputting from a SQL query list of al deactivated users, so there is more than one submit button.

Comment: Now that the ajax issue is fixed... Fix the SQL injection issue NOW... I mean NOW! lol

Comment: Louys, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Im new to this sort of thing.

Comment: Start here... [mysqli prepared statement tutorial](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)... Google for more.

Comment: Will do!  Thank you so much for your time today!

Comment: Thanks Dharman.  Im actually going to convert my PHP to use mysqli per Louys's suggestion.  I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have duplicated the problem in Firefox if the `<button>` element is wrapped with a `<form>`.

What appears to be happening is that clicking the `<button>` is triggering the JavaScript event handler, but it's also triggering a form submission that aborts the script before it completes its AJAX call.

The answer is to disable the form submission.

```
<script>
    function reactivateThisUser(id)
        {
        // prevent default action
        window.event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reactivate-user.php",
        data: 'id='+id,
        cache: false,
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've no idea why there is a difference between Chrome and Firefox. I tried this new version in both and both seem fine.

Comment: About the differrence between FF and Chrome: I just came accross a Chrome setting (while looking for something else): `Settings -> Privacy and security -> Background Sync -> Allow recently closed sites to finish sending and receiving data`. -- Default is true